# (params[:id]) changes after method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to call a method in my controller which changes a bool on an object. Basically the user clicks 'verify' and this is called: `verify_business_path(b)`

I am at the URL users/id/dashboard. According to the logs it passes the correct ID and calls the URL businesses/id/verify. The ID in both these urls is different. Then the verify method is called:

```
def verify
   @business = Business.find(params[:id])
   if current_user.admin?
    @business.update_attribute(:verified, true) 
    if @business.save
      redirect_to dashboard_user_path(current_user.id)
    else
      redirect_to destroy_user_session
    end
   end
   # save, render, etc
 end
```

The ID this gets is wrong. It gets the user ID and not the business ID as you can see in the logs:

```
Started GET "/businesses/30/verify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-10 15:22:20 +0100
Processing by BusinessesController#verify as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"30"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/13/dashboard
Filter chain halted as :check_if_admin rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

How can I get the verify method to use the business ID not the user ID?

Thanks

Edit:

You can see in the logs it passes the correct parameter (business ID) on the 3rd line but on the 4th runs the query with the wrong parameter (current user ID).

Comment: `Filter chain halted as :check_if_admin rendered or redirected` it means your verify method is not executing itself check for `before_filter` methods

Comment: @Salil You're right I removed that filter and it worked. I see what's happening now :) My user was an admin but the before_filter was redirecting before the verify method could execute. Thanks for your help. If you make it an answer I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @salil I was using that filter and another one to redirect users and admins to the correct 'home' page. Is there a way to do it so I can also get the verify method called when necessary?

Comment: @zeantsoi I just accepted your answer. It was correct, I was just giving Salil a chance to post the answer as he got it right first in the comments. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs, the `verify` action is never being executed because of a redirect within the `check_if_admin` action, which is very likely being called in a `before_filter`.

You can ensure that `verify` is executed by removing the `check_if_admin` `before_filter`. If you want to retain the functionality of `check_if_admin`, then add it in your conditional:

```
# app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb
def verify
    @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.admin?
        @business.update_attribute(:verified, true) 
        if @business.save
            redirect_to dashboard_user_path(current_user.id)
        else
            redirect_to destroy_user_session
        end
    else # If user is not an admin 
        # Logic from `check_if_admin`
    end
    # save, render, etc
end
```

Regarding your edit, the logs are actually correct. `Parameters: {"id"=>"30"}` indicates that the business ID is being passed as a param, and `User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 13 LIMIT 1` indicates that there's a lookup to find `current_user`.